# If I want to use native code to analysis in a web application, what should I do?

Tags: php, c, system

Here is the problem...I want the user upload a photo, and after the user uploaded the photo, I will have some processes, to analysis what is the color of this photos. But I don't want to do it on the php... ...because I have a C program that can run it faster. Also, I don't want the user wait for the result. I will notify the user, when the computer analysis it, and have the result the user want. How can I implement it? any ideas or suggestion? Thank you.

My idea on that:

> 1. Write a record in database, when user upload success, for example
>      file001.jpg,  also make a status, for
>      example, status: analysis
> 2. The C program always check whether it have new upload from
>      database
> 3. If have a new upload, get the file001.jpg
> 4. After the C program finish analysis, change the status in
>      database , for example: finish
> 5. The php program using ajax, keep pulling the database, checking
>      the status, if the status changed to
>      "finish", prompt and tell the user.

What do you think about this implementation?

Comment: You want to look into `exec()`

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is perfectly valid.  Essentially you are creating a queuing mechanism to decouple the analysis from the upload.  Your web app validates the upload and then returns to the user, having written an entry to a queue in a DB.

The analysis needs to run as a daemon that is running continually, or possibly as a cron job that starts every x minutes/seconds.  On a set interval it looks at the job queue to see if there is work to be done, if there is, it handles it.  On completion, your daemon updates the database to flag the job as completed, and probably writes new data relating to the analysis into a different table.

Don't forget that if you have multiple processing daemons in the background that you also need to flag a job as 'started' so that a second process doesn't end up duplicating the work.

When the user returns to the page, the new status is reflected.  This can be accomplished 'live' with an Ajax poll as you suggest, or you could look at keeping a live connection open using a Comet approach (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ImageMagick or GD, which you really could unless these photos are HUGE, you are on the right track. If the C program is fast enough, you can do like Pekka says and use exec() to run the C proggy immediately in the initial thread.

I've recently done just this, checking a photo for an over-all color for use in photo-mosaics. We did this with GD and it was pretty straight forward. We shrunk the image down to 1 pixel with resample and then took the color from that. Not 100% perfect, but pretty good for what we are using it for.

Answer (score 0):

Gearman [ http://gearman.org/ ] may be of use to you.

Gearman provides a generic application framework to farm out work to other machines or processes that are better suited to do the work. It allows you to do work in parallel, to load balance processing, and to call functions between languages.

It supports C and PHP, among other languages.  You can write your photo processing script in C as a Gearman worker.  When PHP receives a file upload you can then tell the Gearman daemon to process your photo.  The Gearman daemon will then pick an available worker to do the work and notify you when you work is complete.

It will also speed up your page loading times as the client will not have to wait for the photo processing to be completed before having data sent to their browser.